# columns of joined table missing

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-framework3, zend-db-select

I'm missing the columns of a joined table. I have two tables like:

t_q_filialen 1 --> n t_mandant

I did my select statement in my model as follows:

```
    $select= new Select ();         //another try ('t_mandant','t_q_filialen');
    $select->columns(['id', 'cccid' ,'geschid', 'name', 'langname','filiale']);
    $select->from('t_mandant');
    $select->join('t_q_filialen', 't_q_filialen.id=t_mandant.geschid ', [ 'filialeid'=>'id','filiale'=>'name']);
```

I expected to get the column name with the given alias 'filiale' like this in my view script:

```
$this->escapeHtml($mandant->filiale);
```

I get an error.

> Unknown column 't_mandant.filiale' in 'field list'

If I change back to 'geschid' which is the foreign key-column in the table t_mandant and try:

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($mandant));
```

the columns from the table 't_q_filialen' are not in the collection.

What's wrong?

I have a small idea that I could be something with paginator. I instantiate paginator like this:

```
$resultSetprototype=new ResultSet();
$resultSetprototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Mandant());
$paginatorAdapter= new DbSelect($select, $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(), $resultSetprototype);
$paginator=new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
return $paginator;
```

How can I change this, so that my join will be accepted? Might have something to do with this:

```
$resultSetprototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Mandant());
```

In other models without pagination I use this one and it works:

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->adapter->query($statment, "execute");
```

So which could be the solution? I really would prefer the last possibility, but I have no idea how to use it in combination with paginator. 
Any help appreciated!

I listed several ideas, but my goal would be, to have the columns of both tables in my collection with the paginator-object.

Answer (score 0):

oh my god, I just tried:

```
$paginatorAdapter= new DbSelect($select, $this->tableGateway->getAdapter());
```

Without the resultsetprototype

Comment: Probably in your 'new Mandant()' object you dont have that fields?